# How do I alias a module variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the entry point for my application.

```
from clsConfiguration import clsConfiguration
import also_reads_settings_file
import settings

def main():
    settings.config = clsConfiguration()
    print settings.config.name_prefix
    also_reads_settings_file.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        print "bad stuff happened..."
```

At this time, the settings module is one line and stores a configuration object:

```
config = ""
```

The configuration class, without 20 or so variables:

```
class clsConfiguration:

    def __init__(self):

        self.name_prefix = "ou3_"
        self.app_short_name = "XYZ"
```

Here's module that uses the settings module without initializing it (that's done in the main module):

```
import settings

def main():

    print settings.config.app_short_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        print "bad stuff happened..."
```

Based on the above, how do I create an alias for `settings.config`? In the above, the only way I found to retrieve a value from the configuration object is to use a fully qualified name, `settings.config.app_short_name`.

It would be much easier / better if I could alias the module and variable name as XYZ, for example. The property I'm after becomes `xyz.app_short_name` instead of `settings.config.app_short_name`. Part of this is me just not wanting to deal with the longer names but I also want to avoid refactoring old code to use the longer names.

Comment: I know this is sample code, but please please please remove those pointless except blocks. It's much more useful to get the actual error and traceback from python than a pointless comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
from settings import config
```

or

```
from settings import config as xyz
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: This doesn't work, because the questioner is reassigning `settings.config`.

Comment: `import settings.config as xyz` results in `No module named config`

Comment: `from settings import config` results in AtrributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'app_short_name'`

Comment: `from settings import config as xyz` results in `AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'app_short_name'`